# How often do embedded relative clauses occur in Japanese conversation?

Tags: relative-clauses, conversational

I think the question is clear enough. [I read an article regarding how English speakers comprehend embedded clauses in Japanese](https://www.academypublication.com/issues2/tpls/vol07/10/03.pdf), and how in general it takes more time to comprehend a sentence that requires more mental work to follow; English speakers prefer sentences that with "non-center embedded clauses" and are "short-before-long"; here are examples of each:

> Jacob [in a fast pace] walked to the store. (Center-Embedded Clause)

> Jacob walked to the store [in a fast pace]. (Non-Center-Embedded Clause)

> Socrates [without emotion] stated a chicken that eats its own eggs does not count as cannibalism. (Short-Before-Long)

> Socrates stated a chick that eats its own eggs does not count as cannibalism [without emotion]. (Long-Before-Short)

This is preferred for head-initial languages like English (where the relative clause goes after the subject), but for a head-final language like Japanese (where the relative clause goes before the subject), the preferences are flipped as shown in the examples provided in the research:

> [健が嫌っている]女が議員を褒めた。(Non-Center)

> 女が[健が嫌っている]議員を褒めた。(Center)

The research ultimately showed that native Japanese speaker's better understand non-center and long-before-short (acknowledging as well how は vs. が affects comprehension), which aligns with the first option above. However, these were written examples of sentences, which allow more planning before saying. Basic principles define what is easier to say and comprehend, as well as what one could come up with quicker when actively speaking. I am myself unaware of how often embedded clauses are used in English conversation, but what of Japanese conversation? Given the structural differences in sentence forming, would embedded clauses occur more or less often? I hope someone with more experience with Japanese conversation can answer this.

Comment: But 健が嫌っている女が議員を褒めた and 女が健が嫌っている議員を褒めた mean two different things.

Comment: Maybe the comparison should be between 女が健が嫌っている議員を褒めた and 健が嫌っている議員を女が褒めた?

Comment: I did not like the way the research framed it. I think they are meant to mean different things, but it is just that one is processed faster than the other.

Comment: It's just weird, because the English examples (appear to be intended to) mean the same thing as each other.

Comment: @Leebo I made those examples. I suppose my question was vague to begin with: I suppose I am trying to ask if embedded clauses are as prominent in Japanese conversation as opposed to English conversation. I suppose I should re-upload this with more relevant examples.

Comment: Your use of 'centre-embedding' is misleading. In linguistics, center- embedding normally refers to, for English, a sentence like 'The mouse the cat the dog bit chased ate the cheese.' This is an extreme example, the normal right-branching structure is 'The dog bit the cat which chased the mouse which ate the cheese.'

Comment: 'Thus, when two subject NPs are 
presented consecutively in a sentence such as 'The woman Ken hated praised the senator', readers might find a 
difficulty in figuring out which NP ('The woman' or 'Ken') is the matrix subject or the subordinate subject.' Ahem, if you have a paper copy of this article, burn it, immediately.

Comment: @N.Hunt I see...it was bad research; I am seeing that with regard to how confusing this question became. I hope moderators mark this question as off-topic and I will re-write with a clear frame of reference. The point of my question was that because of the different nature that relative clauses are used in Japanese, I wondered if it decreased or increased their use in conversational Japanese relative to English conversation.